# Proving a strictly decreasing sequence which tends to zero is positive

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a strictly decreasing sequence such that $a_n\underset{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow}0$. I'm asked to prove that $(a_n)$ is positive.

My approach: suppose there is a negative element $a_N$ in the sequence. Let $\varepsilon=-a_N>0$. Then, because $(a_n)$ tends to zero there exists $N_1$ such that for all $n>N_1$: $|a_n|<-a_N \Rightarrow a_N<a_n<-a_N$. Because this is true for all $n>N_1$ it is certainly true for some $N_2$ greater than $N$. Thus $a_{N_2}>a_N$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $(a_n)$ is strictly decreasing.

Is it correct?

Comment: What is $N_1$ compared to $N$?

Comment: @Bib - what do you mean?

Comment: Is $N$ greater than $N_1$? Or does that not matter? Just curious.

Comment: Your solution is correct but to make argument precise choose $N_2> \max\{N,N_1\}$. Then by convergence you have $a_N<a_{N_2}$ but by strictly decreasing condition you will have $a_{N_2}<a_N$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Are you not asked to prove $(a_n)$ is ___strictly___ positive?

Comment: @Bib - it doesn't matter because if $N_1>N$ then **for all** the $n>N_1$ we have $n>N$. Otherwise ($N>N_1$), we still can find $n$ large enough such that $n>N$. But here I think that always $N_1>N$ because $N$ is not inside the radius of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @UrbanPENDU - isn't it redundant? $a_N$ is not inside the radius of $\varepsilon$, so in any case $N_1>N$. Thank you.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - the questions asks to prove that "$(a_n)$ is positive". Maybe it means "strictly positive". But then what is "positive"? "Positive for all but a finite number of $n$"?

Comment: You suppose an $a_N$ is negative. But what if one is zero? Do you consider zero a positive number? In the usual terminology (in English at least) zero is not positive. That is what I meant. The opposite of "positive" is "negative **or zero**".

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - valid point. I don't know. Although I think it still holds even if we include zero.

Comment: Exactly. And I think your proof is incomplete because it does not include the zero case.